# How to get DPI to find current scale in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, scale, dpi

Is there a way to automatically retrieve the DPI value of an OpenLayers page? The goal is to automatically retrieve the map scale from this code:

```
function mapScale (dpi) {
    var unit = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
    var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    var inchesPerMetre = 39.37;

    return resolution * ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[unit] * inchesPerMetre * dpi; }
```

I suppose it should be possible to consider the ScaleLine function which automatically gives the scale.